# Variance form for paired image data

Tags: mixed-model, covariance-matrix

I have a data set where each response y is based on the comparison of two images.  A subject with 4 MRI scans would have 6 y values of a vs b, a vs c, etc.,  each of which is an estimate of the change in volume.  (This is in the context of long term followup of patients through the continuum of unimpaired to 'mild cognitive impairment' to dementia.)  In fitting mixed-effects linear models to this data the variance is not one of the standards, e.g., exchangeable, AR-1, etc.  Anyone have suggestions on how to proceed?

(Each y is the result of a complex process of image alignment and calculation of the non-linear Jacobian that maps one to the other, so there is no underlying '$z$' such that $y(i,j) = z(i) - z(j)$.)

Comment: Is there a reason not to use an unstructured covariance matrix for this?